# How can i update a mysql db column that only depends on a timestamp?

Tags: mysql, database-design, auto-update

Lets say I have a Table `tbl_Room` with a column `taken (boolean)` and a Customer wants to rent this room for a short period.

Now, can I tell mysql to change the value of `taken` automatically depending on the timestamp, e. g. if the rent time/period is over, the value of `taken` should set automatically to false.

Or do I need to update my database with CRON or some other script that runs on the server periodically?

Answer (score 1):

Please use mysql event to manage it.

```
CREATE EVENT [IF NOT EXIST]  event_name
ON SCHEDULE schedule
DO
event_body
```

[Reference](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/)

Under `event_body` you can write select statement to check period and then update table if period is over.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this sort of time-based request is counterintuitive.

Don't try to update the table at a specific time.  Instead, include a timestamp column called something like `lease_expires_at`.

When you rent a room, update the row to set the value of `lease_expires_at` to the time at which the rental period expires.   For example, if you rent a room for 30 minutes, starting now, do this.

```
  UPDATE room
     SET lease_expires_at = NOW() + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
   WHERE room_number = whatever
```

If you want to know whether a room is presently (`NOW()`) taken, do this:

```
 SELECT room_number,
        CASE WHEN lease_expires_at IS NULL THEN 0
             WHEN lease_expires_at <= NOW() THEN 0
             ELSE 1 END taken
   FROM room
  WHERE room = whatever
```

If you want to know whether a room will be available one hour from now (`NOW() + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE`), do this:

```
 SELECT room_number,
        CASE WHEN lease_expires_at IS NULL THEN 0
             WHEN lease_expires_at <= NOW() + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE THEN 0
             ELSE 1 END taken
   FROM room
  WHERE room = whatever
```

Then, once in a while, but not in any time-critical way, you can clean things up using a query like this

```
  UPDATE room SET lease_expires = NULL WHERE lease_expires <= NOW()
```

You can use an event, or an overnight cronjob, or whatever you wish, to do this cleanup. The integrity of your application doesn't depend on exactly when this job runs.

The advantage of this should be clear:  If you rely on some regularly running process to set an `taken` column value, and that process doesn't run or runs late, you get bad results. When you rely on the time, you get accurate results.

There's a small boundary-condition detail in this design. By using `<=` in my queries, I'm choosing to have the `lease_expires_at` timestamp represent the very first moment at which the room is available for another lease, not the last moment of the present lease.  That's a handy choice, because if you put something like `2017-11-2017 11:00:00` into `lease_expires_at`, and somebody says "is the room available at 11:00?" you want to be able easily to say "yes." The guy who rented it at 10:30 gets it until the moment before 11:00.

Answer (score -2):

you can use jquery time picker....after u can create a if loop in which JavaScript time function will check current time...to its original time...if condition is satisfied...we can change the mysql taken function